# Dictionary of lists from two specific columns of a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

The CSV files that I'm dealing with look like this:

```
{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id,begin,end,Emotion
17266,772,781,anticipation
17402,772,781,disgust
17304,1345,1370,disgust
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17472,1578,1602,anger
17525,1611,1617,fear
```

I am trying to create a dictionary of lists, having the `'Emotion'` entries as keys, and the `'begin'` (second column) as the values of the keys that occur in their row.

**Desired output** would look like this:

```
{'anger': [1578,
           2853,
           3951,...],
 'anticipation': [772, 4154, 4400...],
...}
```

So far I've managed to output the desired output, but each value is a list of its own inside of the list of each key.

**My current code:**

```
import pickle
from pprint import pprint
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import csv
from itertools import groupby


root_tk = tkinter.Tk()
root_tk.wm_withdraw()

def extract_gold_emotions():


    """Returns mapping of GOLD emotions to their indices"""



    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()


    l = list(csv.reader(open(filename)))


    f = lambda x: x[-1]


    gold_emo_offsets = {k:list(sorted(map(int, x[1:2])) for x in v)\
                           for k,v in groupby(sorted(l[1:], key=f), f)}


    pickle.dump(gold_emo_offsets, open("empos.p", "wb"))


    return gold_emo_offsets


my_emotions = extract_gold_emotions()
```

**Current output:**

```
{'anger': [[1578], [2853], [3951], [4084], [4693], [6420], [8050]],
 'anticipation': [[772], [4154], [4400], [7392]],....]]}
```

Any hints on what to change in the code to output my desired dictionary of lists?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The dictionary values should be outputted as **integers**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict` and `csv.DictReader`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open(filename) as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)        
    for row in reader:
        d[row["Emotion"]].append(row["begin"])

print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'anger': ['1578'], 'surprise': ['1534', '1534', '1534', '1534'], 'fear': ['1611'], 'anticipation': ['772'], 'disgust': ['772', '1345']})
```

Comment: This works great! I just edited my question: can the numerical values be outputted as **integers** and not as strings?

Comment: Sure use `d[row["Emotion"]].append(int(row["begin"]))`

Answer (score 1):

you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) to get your result dictionary:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

text = '''id,begin,end,Emotion
17266,772,781,anticipation
17402,772,781,disgust
17304,1345,1370,disgust
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17472,1578,1602,anger
17525,1611,1617,fear'''

data = defaultdict(list)

with StringIO(text) as file:
    for row in csv.DictReader(file):
        data[row['Emotion']].append(row['begin'])

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just basic python, no imports (*):

Write file:

```
with open("data.csv","w") as w:
    w.write("""{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id,begin,end,Emotion
17266,772,781,anticipation
17402,772,781,disgust
17304,1345,1370,disgust
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17424,1534,1543,surprise
17472,1578,1602,anger
17525,1611,1617,fear
""")
```

Read and process file:

```
d = {}
with open("data.csv","r") as r:
    next(r) # skip header
    for line in r:
        if line.strip(): # ignore empty lines (f.e. the last one)
            l = line.strip().split(",")
            begin = l[1] # the begin column
            emo = l[-1]  # the emotion column
            k = d.setdefault(emo,[]) # get/create key + empty list if needed
            k.append(begin)            # append to key as string
            # k.append(int(begin))     # append to key but convert to int first

print(d)
```

Output (appended as string):

```
{'anger': ['1578'], 
 'surprise': ['1534', '1534', '1534', '1534'], 
 'fear': ['1611'], 
 'anticipation': ['772'], 
 'disgust': ['772', '1345']}
```

---

(*): You should not parse csv yourself if it containts things like escaped text or "inline/escaped" seperator-characters. You data is *plain* though, and you could parse it yourself.